# Laravel 5: AppServiceProvider vs custom provider

Tags: php, laravel

Few days ago I started to learn Laravel and I can't understand one mechanism: there is AppServiceProvider where I can register (bind) my custom classes, interfaces, etc.. But in many tutorials when author creates custom classes for registration them they also creates custom service provider class instead of using "register" method in AppServiceProvider. And I cann't figure out, why they don't use AppServiceProvider?

Also, I looked at other builtin serviceproviders, and found there some methods and fields that are not described in [official guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers) (for example, AuthServiceProvider has protected $policies field). Maybe, understanding this helps me to understand, where I can use standard provider and where custom? But I can't google any link answering this question.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly it's all about readability of your code. You can probably just put everything in the `AppServiceProvider` and it will work, but over time, the file will be very long and very hard to orientate in so you might want to separate things and make custom ServiceProviders for each part of your application logic.

Answer (score 2):

It really is up to you how you want to structure your files and folders. As for me, I try to make my files modular (separate a piece of functionality within it's own module, e.g. Authentication is a module). Grouping service providers that are related to this module will be in a separate service provider to avoid cluttering the AppServiceProvider.